# What happened when you use table1.* <> table2.*?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Imagine 2 table with the same structure but that might have some rows not equal for the same primary key.

What really happen when using a where clause like this : " `where table1.* <> table2.*` " ?

I "used" it in PostgreSQL but I'm interested for other's languages behavior with this weird thing.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is comparing, every column **together** of the first table to every column **together** of the second table. It is the same as writing the [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) explicitly, which would be required if the columns are not in the same order in both tables.

```sql
(t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2) <> (t2.id, t2.col2, t2.col2)
```

or even more verbose

```
t1.id <> t2.id
OR t1.col1 <> t2.col1
OR t1.col2 <> t2.col2
```

But you may want to use `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead of `<>` to consider `null vs not null` as being different/not equal.

Answer (score 1):

In postgres t1.* <> t2.* in this context is expanded to be:

```
(t1.c1, t1.c2, ..., t1.cn) <> (t2.c1, t2.c2, ..., t2.cn)
```

which is the same as:

```
(t1.c1 <> t2.c1) OR (t1.c2 <> t2.c2) OR ...
```

I think the expansion is a postgres extension to the standard, tuple comparision exists in several other DBMS. You can read about it at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS

The number of columns is required to be the same when comparing tuples, but
I discovered something peculiar when trying your example:

```
create table ta (a1 int);
create table tb (b1 int, y int);
select * from ta cross join tb where ta.* <> tb.*
```

The last select succeds, despite the tuples having different number of columns. Adding some rows change that:

```
insert into ta values (1),(2);
insert into tb values (2,1),(3,4);
select * from ta cross join tb where ta.* <> tb.* 
ERROR:  cannot compare record types with different numbers of columns
```

so it appears as this is not checked when the statement is prepared. Expanding the tuple manually yields an ERROR even with empty tables:

```
select * from ta cross join tb where (ta.a1, ta.a1) <> (tb.b1, y, y); 
ERROR:  unequal number of entries in row expressions
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1YrxaA1)

Comment: Yes, this is a Postgresql specific feature.